# How to Generate border width utilities using scss

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello guys I have a list of classes I want to generate this classes to work with border-width Propertie for example :

How can I do this using **SCSS**

**Class** *line-y-0*

**Properties** *border-top-width: 0;*

```
$line-widths: (
    "line-y-0": 0, // border-top-width: 0;
    "line-x-0": 0, // border-left-width: 0;
    "line-y-2": 2px, // border-top-width: 2px;
    "line-x-2": 2px, // border-left-width: 2px;
    "line-y": 1px, // border-left-width: 1px;
    "line-x": 1px, // border-left-width: 1px;
    "line-y-reverse": 1, // --line-y-reverse: 1;
    "line-x-reverse": 1, // --line-x-reverse: 1;
) !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate all the classes with SCSS loop, but you have to specify the biggest border width. In the example, I have cached it as a variable `$biggest-border-width`.

```
$biggest-border-width: 10;

@for $i from 0 through $biggest-border-width {
  .line-y-#{$i} {
    border-top-width: $i*1px;
  }

  .line-x-#{$i} {
     border-left-width: $i*1px;
  }
}

// Add here the fixed static values so they can overwrite the ones generated with the loop.
.line-y: {
   border-top-width: 1px;
}
```

This code will generate this CSS:

```
.line-y-0 {
  border-top-width: 0px;
}
.line-x-0 {
  border-left-width: 0px;
}
.line-y-1 {
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
.line-x-1 {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.line-y-2 {
  border-top-width: 2px;
}
.line-x-2 {
  border-left-width: 2px;
}
...
```

Comment: thank you it work well but what if I want to add these new classes

Comment: "line-y": 1px,
 "line-x": 1px,
 "line-y-reverse": 1,
 "line-x-reverse": 1

Comment: You can add them outside of the loop. If you add them before the loop, the loop classes will overwrite these and the opposite - if you add them after the loop, they will overwrite the loop ones.

Comment: take a look to the code my friend I jst added some stuff

Comment: So you want `.line-y` to be always 1px and `.line-y-reverse` to be always 1px? What is the idea with those 4 classes?

Comment: yeah my friend please how can I do this

Comment: Remove them from the loop and add them after the loop.

Comment: can you rewrite the code please for more explaination

Comment: I have already done and commented on it, so you know where to add it.

Comment: I can explain more about what I need to do with this image https://i.imgur.com/0E3x1nG.png